# why is there local path being saved to a pickle file for an object

Tags: python, pickle, rasa-nlu

I am saving an object of class via cloudpick to *.pkl file.  But in the saved *.pkl file, I found that a full path of one of my local file is being referred in the binary bytes

This issue is found when I am working in RASA_NLU open source platform, my python version is 3.5.6  .  I've tried google around and explore the RASA_NLU source code, but could not locate the root cause.

class CountVectorsFeaturizer is defined in /home//rasa_nlu/rasa_nlu/featurizers/count_vectors_featurizer.py

```
22 class CountVectorsFeaturizer(Featurizer):
........
........
138     def _tokenizer(self, text):
139         """Override tokenizer in CountVectorizer"""
140         text = re.sub(r'\b[0-9]+\b', '__NUMBER__', text)
141
142         token_pattern = re.compile(self.token_pattern)
143         tokens = token_pattern.findall(text)
144
145         if self.OOV_token:
146             if hasattr(self.vect, 'vocabulary_'):
147                 # CountVectorizer is trained, process for prediction
148                 if self.OOV_token in self.vect.vocabulary_:
149                     tokens = [
150                         t if t in self.vect.vocabulary_.keys()
151                         else self.OOV_token for t in tokens
152                     ]
153             elif self.OOV_words:
154                 # CountVectorizer is not trained, process for train
155                 tokens = [
156                     self.OOV_token if t in self.OOV_words else t
157                     for t in tokens
158                 ]
159
160         return tokens


183     def train(self, training_data, cfg=None, **kwargs):
184         # type: (TrainingData, RasaNLUModelConfig, **Any) -> None
185         """Take parameters from config and
186             construct a new count vectorizer using the sklearn framework."""
187         from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
188
189         spacy_nlp = kwargs.get("spacy_nlp")
190         if spacy_nlp is not None:
191             # create spacy lemma_ for OOV_words
192             self.OOV_words = [t.lemma_
193                               for w in self.OOV_words
194                               for t in spacy_nlp(w)]
195
196         self.vect = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=self.token_pattern,
197                                     strip_accents=self.strip_accents,
198                                     lowercase=self.lowercase,
199                                     stop_words=self.stop_words,
200                                     ngram_range=(self.min_ngram,
201                                                  self.max_ngram),
202                                     max_df=self.max_df,
203                                     min_df=self.min_df,
204                                     max_features=self.max_features,
205                                     tokenizer=self._tokenizer)
207         lem_exs = [self._get_message_text(example)
208                    for example in training_data.intent_examples]
209
210         self._check_OOV_present(lem_exs)
211
212         try:
213             # noinspection PyPep8Naming
214             X = self.vect.fit_transform(lem_exs).toarray()
215         except ValueError:
216             self.vect = None
217             return
218
219         for i, example in enumerate(training_data.intent_examples):
220             # create bag for each example
221             example.set("text_features",
222                   self._combine_with_existing_text_features(example, X[i]))
```

The above class is used to override the existing CountVectorizer of sklearn with some changes like the tokenzier as you can see at line 205.  And after training,  the instanced object of this class would be saved to *.pkl:

```
239     def persist(self, model_dir):
240         # type: (Text) -> Dict[Text, Any]
241         """Persist this model into the passed directory.
242         Returns the metadata necessary to load the model again."""
243
244         featurizer_file = os.path.join(model_dir, self.name + ".pkl")
245         utils.pycloud_pickle(featurizer_file, self)
246         return {"featurizer_file": self.name + ".pkl"}
```

But in the generated *.pkl,  I found a full path of my local file is being saved in it:

```
  4 MethodType~T~E~TR~Th,~L^N_fill_function~T~S~T(h,~L^O_make_skel_func~T~S~Th.~L^HCodeType~T~E~TR~T(K^BK^@K^DK^DK^CCtt^@j^Ad^Ad^B|^A~C^C}^At^@j^B~H^@j^C~C^A}^B|^Bj^D|^A~C^A}^C~H^@j^Erpt^F~H^@j^Gd^C~C^BrX~H^@j^E~H^@j^Gj^Hk^Frp~G^@f^Ad^Dd^E~D^H|^CD^@~C^A}^Cn^X~H^@j    rp~G^@f^Ad^Fd^E~D^H|^CD^@~C^A}^C|^CS^@~T(~L%Override tokenizer in CountVectorizer~T~L
  5 \b[0-9]+\b~T~L
  6 __NUMBER__~T~L^Kvocabulary_~Th8(K^AK^@K^BK^DK^SC&g^@|^@]^^}^A|^A~H^@j^@j^Aj^B~C^@k^Fr^\|^An^D~H^@j^C~Q^Bq^DS^@~T)(h^^h=~L^Dkeys~Th^Xt~T~L^B.0~T~L^At~T~F~T~L~Y/home/<my_local_path>/rasa_nlu/rasa_nlu/featurizers/count_vectors_featurizer.py~T~L
  7 <listcomp>~TK~VC^B^F^A~T~L^Dself~T~E~T)t~TR~T~L5CountVectorsFeaturizer._tokenizer.<locals>.<listcomp>~Th8(K^AK^@K^BK^DK^SC g^@|^@]^X}^A|^A~H^@j^@k^Fr^X~H^@j^An    ^B|^A~Q^Bq^DS^@~T)h^Yh^X~F~ThAhB~F~ThDhEK~\C^B^F^A~ThG~E~T)t~TR~Tt~T(~L^Bre~T~L^Csub~T~L^Gcompile~Th^G~L^Gfindall~Th^X~L^Ghasattr~Th^^h=h^Yt~T(hG~L^Dtext~Th^G~L^Ftokens~Tt~ThD~L
  8 _tokenizer~TK~JC^X^@^B^N^B^L^A
  9 ^B^F^A^L^B^N^B
```

I tried to print the content of the generated *.pkl, here it is:

```
{'OOV_token': None,
 'OOV_words': [],
 'component_config': {'OOV_token': None,
                      'OOV_words': [],
                      'lowercase': True,
                      'max_df': 1.0,
                      'max_features': None,
                      'max_ngram': 2,
                      'min_df': 0.0,
                      'min_ngram': 1,
                      'name': 'intent_featurizer_count_vectors',
                      'stop_words': ['how',
                                     'what',
                                     'hows',
                                     'is',
                                     'the',
                                     'whats'],
                      'strip_accents': None,
                      'token_pattern': '(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b'},
 'lowercase': True,
 'max_df': 1.0,
 'max_features': None,
 'max_ngram': 2,
 'min_df': 0.0,
 'min_ngram': 1,
 'stop_words': ['how', 'what', 'hows', 'is', 'the', 'whats'],
 'strip_accents': None,
 'token_pattern': '(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b',
 'vect': CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', binary=False, decode_error='strict',
        dtype=<class 'numpy.int64'>, encoding='utf-8', input='content',
        lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=None, min_df=0.0,
        ngram_range=(1, 2), preprocessor=None,
        stop_words=['how', 'what', 'hows', 'is', 'the', 'whats'],
        strip_accents=None, token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b',
        tokenizer=<bound method CountVectorsFeaturizer._tokenizer of <rasa_nlu.featurizers.count_vectors_featurizer.CountVectorsFeaturizer object at 0x7ffff67f96a0>>,
        vocabulary=None)}
```

I am trying to understand why this local path is saved here.  I guess it is caused by the callable arugment at line 205 for 'tokenizer', but I could not figure out why.

Wish someone could help me out, thanks in advance.

Comment: which rasa nlu version are you running?

Comment: @Tobias, I uses 1.13.4 version.  Thanks for your comment,  I found another way to work around this without upgrading the version.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in new versions of `rasa` (see [here for the code](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/blob/90f37c70d982cac0bad38ecd8a082041f813cc25/rasa/nlu/featurizers/count_vectors_featurizer.py#L278)). So please consider upgrading to Rasa `1.x`, e.g. by doing `pip install rasa`.